# How to map component with linq to sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql, components, mapping

I have two classes. I want to map Class1 to a database table with linq to sql.

```
[Table(Name = "SomeTable")]
public class Class1
{
    public Class2 Class2
    {
        get; 
        set;
    }
}    

class Class2
{
    public string Name1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name3
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Database table has 3 columns corresponding to the Name-properties of Class2. In NHibernate f.ex., I would use a 'component'-element in the xml-mapping, but how to do with linq to sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, LINQ to SQL doesn't allow this. But as almost always there are several workarounds for it.

The first one is to create a *column-per-complex type property*. See [Complex Types in LINQ-to-SQL—Reloaded](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/csharp/Complex-Types-in-LINQ-to-SQL-Reloaded.aspx) article for more details.

The second one is to associate class `Class2` with a table and add a reference to it in `Class1` (primary/foreign key).

And the last one is to store `Class2` property of a type `Class2` serialized. In the `SomeTable` it could be a column of type `nvarchar(MAX)` if you prefer [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) or e.g. `xml` if you prefer serialization to XML.

Your complex type is pretty simple, so I show an example of how to do it by using `JavaScriptSerializer`. We should add a fake property of type `Class2`, and a private property of type `string` which will actually store the serialized value:

```
public partial class Class1
{
    // this is autogenerated property
    private string Class2Internal {...}

    // this is a fake property
    public Class2 Class2 {get; set;}

    partial void OnLoaded()
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        this.Class2 = serializer.Deserialize<Class2>(this.Class2Internal);
    }

    partial void OnValidate(ChangeAction action)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        this.Class2Internal = serializer.Serialize(this.Class2);
    }
}
```

The `OnLoaded` is called after data is loaded by LINQ to SQL, and `OnValidate` is called before the code is saved - it's the best place for serializing/deserializing (note, that serialization occurs only on saving, and deserialization on entity load).