# linq to sql complex type

Tags: linq-to-sql

Is it possible to create complex/aggregate type that wrap several columns in linq to sql?
This is possible in linq to entities, nhibernate etc. For example we have UsageRange type that have two properties Min, Max. And it is widely used on many tables and have some logic inside getters/setters.

I have found [Dino Esposito](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/csharp/Complex-Types-in-LINQ-to-SQL-Reloaded.aspx) solution, but it seem to me ugly to call track changes manually. Additional fake field I also would like to avoid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to map component with linq to sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693471/how-to-map-component-with-linq-to-sql)